# jQuery autocomplete - amending value of chosen option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following which works as intended to a degree. It brings back the data fine.

If I am searching from the line_manager field, the collar gets updated fine. However if I search from the collar field, the collar field shows the line_manager data.

My question is when I select an option, instead of showing the value brought back in the JSON, how do I show `ui.item.some_other_field` instead?

```
function autoComp(type) {
    $( "."+type ).autocomplete({
          source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax( {
              url: "/searchContacts/json",
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                term: request.term
              },
              success: function( data ) {
                response( data );
              }
            } );
          },
          minLength: 3,
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            var id = $(this).data("id")
            $('input.collar[data-id="'+id+'"]').val(ui.item.collar);
            $('input.line_manager[data-id="'+id+'"]').val(ui.item.forename + ' '  + ui.item.surname);
          }
        } ).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br><small>" + item.department + " / "+item.team+"</small></div>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to do the trick

```
              select: function( event, ui ) {
                var id = $(this).data("id")
                $('input.collar[data-id="'+id+'"]').val(ui.item.collar);
                $('input.line_manager[data-id="'+id+'"]').val(ui.item.forename + ' '  + ui.item.surname);
                return false;
              }
```